# How to copy from one table to another using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass some records from one table to another but I also need to delete those records that have been copied.

The thing that makes this complex is that I need to grab a random bunch of records!

This is what I have been trying the past 2 hours:

```
            $temps = DB::table('temps')->inRandomOrder()->take(3)->get();
            foreach ($temps as $temp) {
                DB::table('videos')->insert(
                    [
                        'idd' => $temp->idd,
                        'title' => '',

                    ]
                );
            }

            foreach($temps as $temp){
                DB::table('temps')->where('idd', '=', $temp->idd)->get()->delete();
            }

            return 'success';
```

If I only want to insert, no problem.

If I want to delete specific records or the whole table, no problem.

However, it's not working if I try to delete the randomly inserted records. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try removing the `get()` from the delete call. `DB::table('temps')->where('idd', '=', $temp->idd)->delete()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing a `delete()` after the `get()` method is incorrect:

```
foreach($temps as $temp){
  DB::table('temps')->where('idd', '=', $temp->idd)->delete();
}
```

or a single query without the loop:

```
DB::table('temps')->whereIn('idd', $temps->pluck('idd'))->delete();
```